# ProductName and CompanyName in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, assemblyinfo

In VB.Net, I can retrieve my application's ProductName and CompanyName by using:

```
My.Application.Info.ProductName
My.Application.Info.CompanyName
```

How do I do the same thing in C#?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? What do you use those for?

Comment: I dynamically generate a path to save settings in.  I often have to recompile code rebranded for a different company, so it's easier to use these values over preprocessor branches.

Comment: Why not write to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Still, a sub-directory of CompanyName/ProductName within %ApplicationData%/ would be wise, don't you think?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, with rfmodulator's amendment, that's exactly what I'm doing. :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use `Assembly` and `FileVersionInfo`

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
var companyName = fvi.CompanyName;
var productName = fvi.ProductName;
var productVersion = fvi.ProductVersion;
```

Comment: I like this.  It doesn't require extra references.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best way for a console application.

Answer (score 10):

Just use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName
System.Windows.Forms.Application.CompanyName
```

...in assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll

Or if you prefer:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
//...
string productName = Application.ProductName;
string companyName = Application.CompanyName;
```

Comment: How have those properties escaped me all this time?  Thanks!

Comment: @Hand-E-Food - After I lost the answer I was afraid you would continue to remain oblivious. :)

Comment: Fine for a Windows form, no good for a class library. I didn't vote down but would have if (anon) down voting didn't annoy me so much with my own posts!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices` namespace.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173136.aspx) for more info.  You can't use the exact same syntax though.  There are also more general .net ways that you would normally use in c# to get the same kind of info you get from My.Whatever in VB but they are completely unrelated to each other. There is no direct equivalent of using My.Whatever in c# the language.

Comment: I always found it odd that C#, for all it's power, doesn't include the niceties found in the VisualBasic namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
var company = new AssemblyInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).CompanyName;
```

Second usage:

```
var codedBy = var company = "Coded by "+(new AssemblyInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).CompanyName);
```